# Need help understanding derivation involving calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I can't follow the derivation in Stellar Photospheres by David F. Gray, 3rd edition, p. 128. How does B follow from A?

- Why do we have *definite* integral from $0$ to $\tau_\nu$ on the right side?
- How do we get $f$ on the left side?

Can anyone explain it rigorously without skipping steps? I've just done my first multivariable calculus unit and not very skilled at this yet. Thanks.

[image: Stellar photospheres p 128]

Comment: The author multiplied through by $e^\tau$ and then integrated with respect to $t_v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that the limits of integration are bothering you, so to add on to DonAntonio's (correct) answer,

Let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$ (here I am using a general function '$f$', not necessarily the one in your book), so that
$$F(x) = \int f(x) dx + c$$
(the "$+c$" is because antiderivatives are unique up to additive constants, and this constant can be added before or after integrating $f$ without harm)

Now, by fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\int_0^x f(t)dt + c = F(x) - F(0) + c$$
Where I used $t$ as the variable of integration just as a matter of convention (you should not integrate over the same variable which appears in your limits, but it is just a placeholder and does **not** cause the integral's value to change).

Now, $F(0)$ is a constant, so we can 'absorb' it into $c$ and just call $c_0 = c - F(0)$ (initial values will take care of this later). Thus,

$$F(x) =  \int_0^x f(t)dt + c_0$$

Hence, the definite integral and indefinite integral representations are completely equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I did not realize that F(0) is the constant. This is a very neat trick that allows to express an indefinite integral as a definite one.

Answer (score 0):

$$A:\;\; e^{-\tau_v}\frac{df}{d\tau_v}=S_v\implies\frac{df}{d\tau_v}=e^{\tau_v}S_v\stackrel{\text{integration}}=f=\int_0^{\tau_v} e^{t_v}S_v\,dt_v+c_0\,,\,\,c_0=\text{constant}$$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand your steps after "integration". Integration with respect to what? How do we end up with just f on the left side. And why do we have definite integral on the right side?

Comment: @Evgenii: you end up with just $f$ on the left side because $\int df = f$ (plus a constant, which can be absorbed into the constant on the right side). The limits of integration issue I addressed in my answer.